# Get JSON data FROM a PHP/MySQL query into a html tag using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Hi guys I´m new at stackoverflow and also new at Jquery

Well hope I can make myself understandable. Here is what I want: I have made a query to my MySQL db, using a class with PHP

```
public function User($id) {
    $this->connect_db_web($conn);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
    while ($values = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $arr[]=array(
        'id'=>$values['idUsers'],
        'name'=>$values['name'],
        'name2'=>$values['name2'],
        'lname'=>$values['lname'],
        'lname2'=>$values['lname2'],
        'email'=>$values['email'],
        'phone'=>$values['phone'],
        'address'=>$values['address'],
        'bday'=>$values['bday'],
        'password'=>$values['password']
        );
    }
    echo '{"user":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
}
```

Then I have a php code where I call this function

```
$name = $user->User($id);
```

I think this works ok (if I´m wrong please help). Now what I´m really trying to do is getting the values from the JSON array into specific divs, example:

```
$.getJSON("user.php",function(data){
$.each(data.user, function(i,user){
    name = user.name;
    $(name).appendTo('#getname');
});
});
```

And inside my HML i Have a `<p id="getname"></p>`wich is the tag I want the value to be displayed

But no value is displayed, why?, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help I apreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably safer to do like this:

```
echo json_encode(array("user" => $arr));
```

on the other end you would receive an object which, I would suggest iterating like this:

var k;

```
for (k in data.user){
     $("#getname").append($("<span></span>").html(data.user[k].name));
}
```

---

Given that you are fetching information for one user only, following I would suggest

```
$id = (int) $_GET["id"]; // or wherever you get it from.
if ($r = $db->mysql_fetch_assoc()){
    $response = array(
        "name" => $r["name"];
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "Could not get name for user " . $id));
}
```

Then, on front-end, all you need to do is:

```
if (typeof(data.name) != "undefined"){
    $("#getname").html(data.name);
} else if (typeof(data.error) != "undefined"){
    $("#getname").html(data.error); //or handle otherwise
}
```

Comment: Hi Jancha, got the same value as with Jens, {users:[]}, what should I do instead?

Comment: seems like problem with data fetching. revisit mysql query, if that works. also -- while loop is not good idea, as you are doing id matching. so there can be only one record. this means that you should optimize everything to start with. will update my note for better solution.

Comment: Actually the data is perfectly displayed, from db, the problem focus in the Jquery getJSON function, it doesn´t display no data, wich is weird. sued your script and same thing it doesn´t get any value, JSON is empty, what the hell can be happening?

Comment: do console.log(data) and paste here results from inspector

Comment: actually I got this from firebug, no data displayed inside the site

Comment: okay, this clearly suggests that problem is with your data fetching script. what I suggest is try adding more echoes to it and make sure it really fetches data. make sure that backend really works. problem is clearly there.

Comment: I did an include in the top of the page and so I can see all data displayed, so not sure what it is

Comment: this is what it shows:{"users":[{"id":"1","name":"username","name2":"user2ndname","lname":"lastname","lname2":"2ndlastname","email":"email@domain.com","phone":"555.555.555","address":"useraddress","bday":"30\/12","password":"12345"}]}

Comment: I am sorry I went in and saw it was not accepted, better after than never!!

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is malformed. You are appending a bunch of objects `{.1.}{.2.}{.3.}`. Instead, try `{"users":[{.1.},{.2.},{.3.}]}`.

In PHP you'll do something like this (note that I've changed the response type to JSON-P rather than JSON by adding a `callback` parameter):

```
public function User($id) {
    $users = array();

    $this->connect_db_web($conn);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
    while ($values = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $users[] = array(
          'id'=>$values['idUsers'],
          'name'=>$values['name']
          // etc.
        );
    }
    $obj['users'] = $users;

    $callback = (empty($_GET["callback"])) ? 'callback' : $_GET["callback"];
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($obj) . ');';
}
```

Then you'll be able to do:

```
$.getJSON("user.php?callback=",function(data){
  $.each(data.users, function(i,user){
    $('#getname').append(user.name);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Jens, using your code, it all went very nice, at least I´m getting values, but for some reason I still get null, using firebug I get {"users":[]} why is that so?

Comment: Are you loading the JSON from a different (sub)domain? Then it could be a cross-domain policy issue. Try JSON-P instead. I'll update the code

Comment: No Jens, same site same domain, actually is a localhost test site, so nothing from outside

Comment: Oh wait. Your DIV id is `getname` (no caps) but my jQuery selector was `$('#getName')` (capital N). Change THAT and try again.

Comment: I realize that, that´s not it, the difficulty is that JSON is not displaying and values in JQeury format, I have the values from the php class, but cannot get them using Jquery, I alway get Null or {users:[]} (taked from firebug)

Comment: Hmm.... Maybe check the response headers (content-type and encoding) of your PHP script?

Comment: hmmm maybe that could be it, let me check

Comment: If that doesn't work, could you post a link to the PHP script so we can check the output?

Answer (score 0):

You've misinterpreted your JSON structure. You're appending your DB rows to an array, and embedding that inside an object. If you'd do a `console.log(user)` inside your .getJSON call, you'd see you'll have to do:

```
user[0].name
```

instead. As well, your code assumes that the user ID exists, and returns data regardless of how many, or how few, rows there actually are in the result set. At minimum your JS code code should check `users.length` to see if there ARE are any rows to begin with. Beyond that, unless you're doing it in another section of code somewhere, that `$id` value is probably coming from the web page, which means your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

**OK got it,
was a php code error and JSON structre as marc said, here I´m gonna post what finally I had
PHP Class**

```
public function User() {
$users = array();
$this->connect($conn);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1'");
    $values = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $users[] = array(
            'id'=>$values['id'],
            'name'=>$values['name'],
            'name2'=>$values['name2'],
            'lname'=>$values['lname'],
            ...//rest of values
            );

    echo json_encode($users);
}
```

**PHP module to get class**

```
include"class.php";
$user = new Users();
$user->User();
```

**Now how did I got the values using JQuery**

```
$.getJSON('user.php', function(data){
        $('wherever_you_want_to_point_at').text(data[0].name);
    });
```

*Hope it helps someone,
Thanks again guys, very very helpful
Take care you all*